# Mongo search structure

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have several collections that should be searched when searching for words.
Those collections are them merged on a single search collection.
I Have some fields that are fullText and some fields that are a array of text tags.Those tags come from several contexts

Considering that mongo just use ONE index per search, and that a [compound index can only contain one array field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/)  . I am inclined to put all tags on a set on some field of this search structure.

My Question Is: What about the fullText fields? Should i just concat them and add them as some huge text field?

Should i just skip mongo alltogether and input my fields on some other Database?

Comment: If you need complex full text search capabilities (or if the full text search is the primary purpose of your app), I would recommend using a specialized full test search engine like elastic search or solr. You can, however, [index multiple text fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/) in MongoDB.

Comment: Cool. Will use mongo for now and try the other two options as soon as possible

Comment: MongoDB Atlas now supports Lucene powered full text search (similar to Elastic and Solr) as well.  https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having using my solution on production for some time i have the following conclusions:

- Keeping all the arrays on a single field for indexing even for large datasets is good enough;
- A specialized text engine , altough increasing the technology stack, is more powerfull and scalable and i would recommend [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch)